# Active Model Serializer not working with json_api adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, active-model-serializers

I am trying to use custom serializers for the relationships in a serializer and the json_api adapter enabled. However the relationships are not serialized correctly (or, better, not at all displayed/serialized).

**PostController.rb**

```
def index
  render json: Post.all, each_serializer: Serializers::PostSerializer
end
```

**Serializer**

```
module Api
  module V1
    module Serializers
      class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
        attributes :title, :id

        belongs_to :author, serializer: UserSerializer
        has_many :post_sections, serializer: PostSectionSerializer
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**JSON output:**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "title": "Test Title"
            },
            "id": "1",
            "relationships": {
                "author": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": "1",
                        "type": "users"
                    }
                },
                "post_sections": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "type": "post_sections"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "type": "posts"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the relationships are not fulfilled, which happens **only if I specify a custom serializer** for the relationships!!

If I do something like this:

```
module Api
  module V1
    module Serializers
      class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
        attributes :title, :id

        belongs_to :author # no custom serializer!
        has_many :post_sections # no custom serializer!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The relationships are shown correctly, but not using a custom serializer... 
What's the issue here ?

## EDIT

According to the [json API 1.0 Format](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-identifier-objects), what I am getting back is the so-called `resource identifier object`.

> The following primary data is a single resource identifier object that
>   references the same resource:
>
> {   "data": {
>       "type": "articles",
>       "id": "1"   } }

Is there a way to prevent getting resource identifier objects, and get the actual data instead ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relationships only returns `id` and `type` according to [json-api exmaples](http://jsonapi.org/examples/). If you need to return more information about this relation you should add `include` option on your render action.

Ex.

**PostController.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render json: @post, include: 'comments'
  end
end
```

**Serializers**

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :content
  has_many :comment, serializer: CommentSerializer
end

class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :content
end
```

**JSON output:**

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "post",
        "attributes": {
            "title": "bla",
            "content": "bla"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "comment": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "type": "comments",
                        "id": "1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "included": {
        {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "comments",
            "attributes": {
                "title": "test",
                "content": "test"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @chris-peters or Bruno: Is there a way to do include associations by default in the serializer without having to do it in the controller at every place where we call render? Is there an include option that we could append to has_one/has_many associations in the serializer?

Comment: @geoboy Looks like someone else had the same thought today: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1333 The issue indicates that that sort of thing isn't yet available.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @Bruno Bacarini's answer, you may also include chained associations by using:

```
render @posts, include: ['authors.profile', 'comments']
```

source: [joaomdmoura's comment on github](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1056#issuecomment-131824759)